# Argocd image updater giving Could not get tags from registry: denied: Failed to read tags for host 'gcr.io' Error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, flux, argocd

I am trying to use the ArgoCd-image-updater , but it is giving me the below error

```
time="2022-09-13T15:40:02Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint '^0.1' when looking for a new tag" alias= application=ms-echoserver-imageupdate-test image_name=test-build/argo-imageupdater-test image_tag=0.9 registry=gcr.io
time="2022-09-13T15:40:02Z" level=error msg="Could not get tags from registry: denied: Failed to read tags for host 'gcr.io', repository '/v2/test-build/argo-imageupdater-test/tags/list'" alias= application=ms-echoserver-imageupdate-test image_name=test-build/argo-imageupdater-test image_tag=0.9 registry=gcr.io
time="2022-09-13T15:40:02Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=1 images_skipped=0 images_updated=0 errors=1"
```

My argocd image updater config file:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-image-updater-config
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-image-updater-config
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd-image-updater

data:
  log.level: debug
  registries.conf: |
    registries:
    - name: Google Container Registry
      api_url: https://gcr.io
      ping: no
      prefix: gcr.io
      credentials: pullsecret:argocd/gcr-imageupdater
      #credentials: secret:argocd/sundayy#creds
```

Note:- Secret is having owner permission.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was that I was using the *test* command without specifing the configuration of the registry because I assumed that it will take the default config file, but it doesn't. So try this:

```
argocd-image-updater test gcr.io/myproject/myimage --registries-conf-path="/app/config/registries.conf"
```

Or use the command *run* instead of *test*

Hope it helps.